# how to change Java cache folder automatically for WebStart programs

Tags: java, caching

We have a java application deployed in a local LAN, which is cached in JRE cache folder. By default this cache space can be up to 1GB in size and in most cases here all computers have used that space in total.

This will not be an issue if there is no need for doing daily backups of all user's home folders in LAN (and there are more than 200 computers in LAN).

So, by synchronizing user's home folder batch procedure also synchronizes java cache folder weighing 1GB what in total produces 200x1GB traffic what concerns network administrator.

Solution is to put java cache folder somewhere outside user's home folder, but that can be done only through control panel. That requires someone to go visit all 200 computers and change that manually... or maybe there is a solution that could do job automatically?

Comment: Are you referring to Java WebStart?

Comment: yes, we use Java WebStart as a deployment 'tool', and WebStart cache jars to application temp folder ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to change the `deployment.user.cachedir` property in `deployment.properties`

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html