# How to change the path of the cache directory in java ,or how to customize it for any user?

Tags: java

I want to change the path of : `C:\Documents and Settings\abc\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache` to any specified Location

How to customize deployment.properties file but the changes should be generic to any user,i dont need to to it for every user.

Is there any way to do it??

Answer (score 2):

The default java cache directory can be changed from within your windows interface by:

`control panel>Java > General > Setting > Location`

That's the general location of java cached files.

Note: if the Change button is disabled, go to your `JRE>bin` directory and change the  `javacpl.exe` to run in compatibility mode (`Windows XP (Service Pack 3)`)

Now if you are using java WebStart as your deployment tool, please refer to this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html)
and change the `deployment.user.cachedir` property in `deployment.properties`.

There is a `deployment.properties` file for every java installation. In my java configuration the location of this file is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment`.

Refer also to [how to change Java cache folder automatically for WebStart programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310463/how-to-change-java-cache-folder-automatically-for-webstart-programs)

Comment: but there is no such property as deployment.user.cachedir in deployment.properties file.so how to add it ??i have gone through the links u mentioned bt it is saying the same thing .please reply urgently.need it badly

Comment: have you checked this https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10834710 ?

Comment: Client applicaiton application is deployed on jboss server. Shares the web link. When we click the link, java web start gets invoked and start downlaoding the jars in the folloing the location:  C:\Documents and Settings\abc\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache, i want to downlad the jar in a specific folder on my local folder. i am trying from the command prompot using the following command: javaws -silent -import -codebase http://170.198.83.195/ClinetBlade/usfi http://170.198.83.195/ClinetBlade/fi/1.5/MDI1.jnlp, is there any option to specify cache directory pointing to my localfolder

Comment: in above comment,i hv tried to tell what exactly i m doiong ,and what i want..please go through it ,u will come to knw....??